# How to find the index of undetermined pattern in a string?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I want to find the index of multiple occurrences of at least two zeros followed by at least two ones (e.g., '0011','00011', '000111' and so on), from a string (called 'S')
The string ***S*** may look like:

'00111001100011'

The code I tried can only spot occurrences of '0011', and strangely returns the index of the first '1'. For example for the ***S*** above, my code returns 2 instead of 0:

```
index = []
index = [n for n in range(len(S)) if S.find('0011', n) == n]
```

Then I tried to use regular expression but I the regex I found can't express the specific digit I want (like '0' and '1')

Could anyone kindly come up with a solution, and tell me why my first result returns index of '1' instead of '0'? Lot's f thanks in advance!!!!!

Comment: Correcting `string` to `S`, and changing `n-1` to `n` (I don't know why you thought it was necessary to subtract 1), this works fine. What's the problem?

Comment: I'm no regexp buff but what's wrong with `00+11+`?

Comment: A simple translation of your pattern into regex could be `0{2,}1{2,}`

Comment: `can't express the specific digit I want (like '0' and '1')` sure it can.

Comment: @PaulPanzer I think rather `0+1+` since you want at least *two* of each. In any event, laziness vs eagerness will have to be specified by the OP

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - `0+1+` will accept one of each. `00+11+` is "0, then one or more 0s, then 1, then one or more 1s." The OP's code basically works anyway.

Comment: Corrected, thanks! My problem is that I can only find '0011', but I want the occurrence of at least two 0's followed by at least two 1's ( '0011' or 0001111' or '00111' or '000011' from the string S and find out the index of the first '0' if it's followed by more than two 0's and 1's (sorry a bit confusing). For example, for the S above, I want to return [0, 5, 9]

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 oops, you're right. This is why I tend to use the curly bracket quantifiers...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga doesn't '0+' match _one_ ore more occurrences?

Comment: @June_Stephanie, don't reinvent the wheel, just use a regex as suggested in comments above.

Comment: @PaulPanzer yes, yes. My mistake :)

Comment: @PaulPanzer I tried 00+11+ but the index list returns empty. So I assume python recognize the expression as a string instead of repex. So Python searches for '00+11+' in S (and finds nothing).

Comment: It works for me try: `template = re.compile('00+11+')` and then `for m in template.finditer(<yourstring>):` this should cycle through all occurrences. m will be match objects. Just play with them, they'll give the index and substring

Comment: "I assume python recognize the expression as a string instead of repex" - Did you make any effort to use a regular expression, or did you just pass `'00+11+'` to `S.find`?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3  I got stuck on this for at least one hour and asking here is my last resort. I search Stackoverflow for similar questions, learn regex on regex101.com, and using different functions and modules appears useful. But nothing works for me. Thanks for helping though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following code the regex defines a single instance of the required pattern of digits. Then uses the `finditer` iterator of the regex to identify successive matches in the given string `S`. `match.start()` gives the starting position of each of these matches, and the entire list is returned to `starts`.

```
S = '00111001100011'
r = re.compile(r'(0{2,}1{2,})')
starts = [match.start() for match in r.finditer(S)]
print(starts)
# [0, 5, 9]
```

Comment: clever use of finditer()!